# Django manage.py runserver fails to respond

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm running a vagrant box on Mac OS X. The VM is running Ubuntu 12.04, with Python 2.7 and Django 1.4.5. When I start up manage.py, I call it like this:

`./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

And if I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000` from within the VM, the text browsers I've tried report that the HTTP request has been sent and then wait for a response until the request times out. No response ever comes.

I can telnet to the port like this:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 8000`

And enter random gibberish, which manage.py reports as the following:

`127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2014 17:06:26] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('asdfasdfadsfasd')
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2014 17:06:26] "asdfasdfadsfasd" 400 -`

So manage.py is listening on that port. But a standard HTTP request generates no response from manage.py, either in the console or in the browser.

I've tried using different ports which hasn't had any effect. Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Some additional curl output.

Executing 'curl -v `http://127.0.0.1:8000`' returns
'* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
>   Accept: */*
>   '

Executing 'curl -v `http://somefakedomain`' results in
'* getaddrinfo(3) failed for somefakedomain:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'somefakedomain'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host somefakedomain'

Comment: How do you know that this is the server's fault and not your app's? if you set a breakpoint somewhere in the urls can you see it being hit?

Comment: Do you have a port forwarding for some port to 8000 on the vagrant box?

Comment: Try `GET /` from within the telnet session.

Comment: @C.B. Port forwarding isn't relevant just yet, as I'm working exclusively within the VM to ensure Django works there first.

Comment: @Ashish I gave 'GET /' a try - no response from manage.py. Very odd.

Comment: @user940281, that means that there is something wrong with the view that handles the `/` url. My guess is that if you try any other URL in the browser it should work just fine.

Comment: @matcheek The app is working fine from the same branch of the repo on other users' VMs.

Comment: just to be clear, by standard HTTP request, are you using something like curl (within the VM), firefox (again within the VM), or some other browser but from your mac?  Also, if you do e.g. curl http://localhost/thisisfake, do you get a 404 or still no response?

Comment: @Foon I'm working exclusively in the VM via 'vagrant ssh' to try get this up and running. I've tried with curl, lynx and w3m.

Comment: my initial suggestion on doing curl http://localhost/thisisfake (as opposed to curl http://fakedomain/) still stands, failing that, I'd suggest trying to narrow things done by stopping your django runserver and doing python -m SimpleHTTPServer to start a simple webserver to isolate between Django and some weird firewall or what not...

Comment: Right.

Problem solved. It turns out there was a call to a service that was failing on application startup. No errors were being thrown, but some snooping with ipdb sorted it out.

So it was a Django error, not a VM issue after all. The code has been modified to throw an error if this happens again in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so to reiterate my last post.

There was a call to a Django service that was failing on application startup. No error was thrown, instead it was absorbed by Sentry. Those who were already using the VM on their local machines had worked around the issue.

The issue was identified by importing ipdb and calling its set_trace() function. From the console, I stepped through the application, testing likely variables and return values until it refused to continue. This narrowed it down to the misbehaving service and its unthrown error.

The code has been updated with proper try/catch blocks and the error is now handled gracefully.

So to summarise: Not a malfunctioning VM, but a problem with code.